# Tallis gadol with white stripes

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, tallit-gadol, color

An interesting question has been posted on the signification of tallis' stripes : [Stripes on a Talis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4501/stripes-on-a-talis)

About stripes color the Rambam position's noticed as black being closer to techeiles color.
My question : what is the signification and origin of the white stripes worn for example by some mizrahi communities as Rav Ovadia Yosef shlita himself ?

Comment: I have heard that according to the kabbalist it is preferable to have white stripes on the tallis. I don't remember the reasoning though.

Comment: @Dude - white represents chesed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Kaf Hachaim (9:15)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14418&pgnum=50) brings many sources and reasons why the Talit itself should be completely white (although he says black stripes at the bottom do not invalidate this, since we look at the majority of the Talit).

A couple of the reasons he brings:

- Shulchan Aruch says that the Tzitzit should be the same color as the garment, since the strings are white, the Talit should also be white.
- Gemara [Rosh Hashanah 17B](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1319&size=1) says that G-d wore a Tallit when telling Moshe the 13 Attributes of Mercy. G-d then told Moshe if the Jews do as I have done they will be forgiven. In [Daniel 7:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16490) it says "*I was looking until thrones were set up, and the Ancient of Days sat; His raiment was as white as snow...*", so we see G-d has a white Tallit. So in order to do as G-d had done, wear a completely white Tallit.