# Decorated Tallis gadol

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, tallit-gadol

It is quite common to see people with colorfully decorated tallises in non-Orthodox (especially Conservative) shuls, but much less common to see the same thing in Orthodox shuls. Is there any halachic issue with having a decorated tallis gadol?

Comment: Very related and maybe dupe: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10594/does-a-tallis-have-to-be-of-a-certain-color Also: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4501/stripes-on-a-talis Also: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8321/tallis-gadol-with-white-stripes

Comment: @IsaacMoses I agree.

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure if you have a red or blue talith, the sSisSith have to be the same color, with a techeilath in the middle. I am not sure as to why Orthodox Jews don't wear colorful taleithim, but the closest I saw to colorful was a regular talith with blue stripes instead if black. In yemen, the teimonim wore a talith Jodol all day in and out of shul, some wore a black cloth with I assume black sSisSith on them.

Comment: taleithim? really? If you're going to be Makpid on the thau, you might at least be Makpid on the grammar. ;-)

Comment: Aye I'm typing on my phone as fast as I can. I'd rather stick with a word my phone gets that with a word that's going to be auto corrected 10times

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob, Ashkenazim don't hold by that. Furthermore, the people today who will have a colourful tallit will typically not be makpid on the matter. For an example which I once saw at a Chabad: black beged, colourful stripes, white tzitziot.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt just because people are in the wrong today doesnt mean it is right and one should learn from that

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob, agreed, although I read somewhere here that Tosafot hold that one should always use white strings based on a pasuk in Daniel.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob I remember reading that white tzitzis can be used with a multicolored beged but do not yet have the source.