# Were there any instances of Ashkenazim using a tallit with white stripes?

Tags: minhag, tallit-gadol

I heard that such tallits were worn by Yekke and Yemey Norayim. Did anyone else use white stripes from Ashkenazim?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8321/27180 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4501/27180

Comment: For Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur yes

Comment: The Maharshal ...