# Stripes on talis with techeilet

Tags: halacha, tallit-gadol, techeles

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4503/1713) mentions says that the stripes on the tallis are reminiscent of techeilet. Now, we have a few different dyes that claim to be techeilet, which many people wear. Usually, talises with techeilet also have the stripes. Do they need to have them?  If so, should the stripes on the talis match the color of the techeilet string?

Comment: "Do they need to have them?" Are you assuming _talisos_ **without** _t'cheles_ need stripes? If so, is that merely an assumption or something you've sourced? If the latter, you may wish to mention as much in your question.

Comment: @msh210 I'm not assuming anything. I don't necessarily mean that they *need* them halachically. I guess I'm just wondering whether whatever guidelines exist about talis-making have any connection between tcheiles strings and the stripes. I'm assuming that some guidelines exist (either as minhag or in some other form) based on the fact that nearly all talitot have stripes of some form.

Comment: "I'm not assuming anything....I'm assuming that some guidelines exist..." There's nothing wrong with making assumptions as long as you know what they are, are clear about them, and try to offer whatever justification you have for making them.

Answer (score 1):

the stripes are not "needed" they are a Minhag. accordingly, talisim were not origionally striped. I take the liberty to guess that manufactures of todays talisim with techeileit that have stripes as well, are simply producing it according to peoples perceptions of what a talis should look like. In regard to the color, i'ts interesting to note the the Hassidic sect of Belz has in recent years changed the color of the stripes on their non-techeilet talisim to a more blue/ light blue color- presumably to more closely match the original color.

Comment: Hi user4550! We don't know you, so your guess, as free as you are to make it, is not worth very much to us. Try to back it up with a source so we can verify it.