# PTIJ: Did the Persian Sefer Divrei Hayamin have color pictures?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

After having been read the story of Bigsana Visseresh, Achashveirosh asks if Mordechai was rewarded. Well, he heard the story as well as the guy reciting it. What's the point in asking about the story if it's not in the book?

The obvious answer is, that the guy reading it can see the pictures. So this leaves me wondering if they were color pictures, black & white, or sepia?

Comment: Besides, Achashveirosh wanted the book read to him when he couldn't sleep, and everyone knows the best bedtime stories have pictures!

Answer (score 2):

Actually their "black" ink was more blue-ish, so "B&W" photos were actually blue-and-white:

> ומרדכי יצא מלפני המלך בלבוש מלכות תכלת וחור
>
> The king had Mordechai printed up in *Royal Garb* magazine, in blue and white.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65421/blue-stripes-on-tallis

Comment: Pretty inventive on that '_Royal Garb_'.