Why Does Belz Wear Blue?
Why does the Belz Chasidus wear dark navy stripes on their tails? What is the source of this minhag? It seems to be a more recent development.

Also, see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65421/blue-stripes-on-tallis

Chassidic dress is the style in Europe at the formalization of a particular chassidus.
